# An odd situation w. Python and Scope

Tags: python, constants, scope

to be more specific, I'll show the code, then explain what is occurring.

```
DATE = 'November'

def commander():
    pass

class Circle():
    pass

def log(orig_stdout, rep_log):
    pass

def debug(debugBool, info):
    pass

def main():
    Date = DATE
```

So pretend that each of the functions are filled out, that isn't the important part. What IS important is that `main()` can't see `DATE`, and I get the usual `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'DATE' referenced before assignment"` exception.

I thought that constants had global scope? What's weirder is that it was working fine before, but only now is causing problems. If you'd LIKE I could show you the rest of the code, but it's a tad messy.

TL;DR: The scope of DATE doesn't reach the main function, why?

Comment: Please fix your formatting - as it stands now this is invalid python code, and I can't quite guess at how it ought to be indented.

Comment: the read scope should ... but if you are assigning to DATE at all you need to do global DATE ... or it will think your talking about the DATE you are assigning which is only local (unless you explicitly say global DATE, prior to setting it)

Comment: This example provided works for me. Most likely, main() contains an assignment to DATE that is not shown in the example (see the answer below)

Comment: that is also my suspicion ;)

Comment: Figured out the problem, it was as Beasley says, I had a DATE being reassigned in the main(), it was quite hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GOOD , only reads... therefor it must be the GLOBALLY Scoped DATE

```
DATE = "November"
def main():
    xyz=DATE
    print "Date :",DATE
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

BAD (w/ error) , this happens because python thinks the DATE you are talking about is the DATE you assign to later, which is a LOCAL variable which shadows the GLOBAL one.

```
DATE = "November"
def main():
    xyz=DATE
    print "Date :",DATE
    DATE = 123
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

GooD (again)!!! , now python knows you are talking about the GLOBAL variable DATE

```
DATE = "November"
def main():
    global DATE
    xyz=DATE
    print "Date :",DATE
    DATE = 123
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

at least that is my understanding of Globals.  typically a better practice is to use arguments with default variables

```
def main(my_date=DATE):
   #now there is no question and it will use global scope
   #the downside is it is set to the value of DATE at run start not at the time it goes to main
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that DATE in ``xyz=DATE`` is a global name, it's a FREE name, according to definition in the doc: _"If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable."_ (and I dislike this use of the word 'variable'). So ``DATE=123`` tends to make DATE a LOCAL name, and that is conflicting with the preceding status of FREE name for the same one. The statement ``global DATE`` prevents the name DATE to be considered LOCAL by the interpreter just because of the assignement ``DATE=123``

Comment: from a definition standpoint you are correct.  however from a practical standpoint I believe my statements to be true(I havent seen any behaviour other than what I stated above,  there may be some cases where what I said above is false however).

Comment: i guess i'll respond here, your example of setting global beforehand worked, but this becomes an issue since i have a LOT of global variables. . .